# Linux shows much less disk space then summary of all disks

Tags: linux, centos, disk-space-utilization

I have a CentOS server with 4 disks, each with 1TB that totals to 3.636 TB of usable space (according to http://www.jonathanlaliberte.com/2007/12/18/calculating-actual-hard-disk-space/).

But the server df command shows the following status:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              5.5G  3.0G  2.3G  57% /
/dev/md3              2.7T  2.7T   55G  99% /media
/dev/md0              181M   12M  160M   7% /boot
```

The swap is:

```
Swap:         5721         12       5708
```

So on overall, I'm about 900 GB short.

Any idea where that space went, and how I can get it back?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, this is the status after I already set the amount of reserved blocks on /dev/md3 to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are the MD devices configured? If you use a RAID1 (mirroring) or Raid5 (striped with parity), you will loose capacity. A RAID1 will have half the capacity of all disks, and a RAID5 will have the capacity of n-1 disks.

Comment: Good call.  4 1TB disks in RAID 5 will give you approximately 2.72 TB

Comment: (s/loose/lose/)

Comment: Wow, I managed to completely forget how RAID 5 works. Speaking of overwork... Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following commands

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo parted -l
```

Should shed more light on what is going on, giving you the exact reported capacity of your drives that the OS sees. How is your RAID set up?

Comment: RAID 5, which explains the missing 25%.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like sofware raid (/dev/md* devices belongs to linux md raid). Probably there is something like raid5. Take a look to /proc/mdstat.

Comment: RAID 5 indeed, completely forgot it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

The usable space calculation on the website appears to just convert between GB and GiB, without any consideration for file system structures, reserved space, your RAID arrays (and their overhead) and so on.  Furthermore, it's entirely possible that you have unpartitioned space on the drives or other partitions that aren't mounted.

Check `cat /proc/partitions` to see the actual partition and device size information (in 1KiB blocks) not counting the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

For all we know, the 900 GB could be unpartitioned space. Also, 2.7T is not very precise. 
Try `df -k` to see the file system size in KiB instead.

You need to show how the metadevices are configured, and how the 4 disks are partitioned.

`cat /proc/mdstat` should be a good starting point.